# Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals and println

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-playground

I'm learning Swift and I have a doubt regarding Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals.

I have a function returning a String optional:

```
func findApt(aptNumber :String) -> String?
{
    let aptNumbers = ["101", "202", "303", "404"]
    for element in aptNumbers
    {
        if (element == aptNumber)
        {
            return aptNumber
        }
    } // END OF for LOOP
    return nil
}
```

and an if statement to perform safe unwrapping, which uses an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional as its constant:

```
if let apt :String! = findApt("404")
{
    apt
    println(apt)
    println("Apartment found: \(apt)")
}
```

In the first line **apt** unwraps itself as it should (the results pane shows *"404"*), but in the other two lines **apt** does not unwrap: both the results pane and the console show that the printed values are *Optional("404")* and *Apartment found: Optional("404")*, and in order for *404* to appear on console I have to use the ! symbol, which, if I understand correctly, is only needed to manually unwrap regular Optionals.

Why does it happen?

My guess is that, when passed to println(), **apt** is implicitly converted from Implicitly Unwrapped Optional to regular Optional, which causes the *Optional("404")* text to appear, but I'd like some expert advice on the matter, as I'm just a beginner with the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let apt :String! = findApt("404")` won't unwrap the optional since you are explicitly using an Optional type which is `String!`

If you want to unwrap the optional use:

```
if let apt: String = findApt("404")
{
  ...
}
```

or better, using type inference:

```
if let apt = findApt("404")
{
  ...
}
```

> In the first line apt unwraps itself as it should (the results pane
>   shows "404"), but in the other two lines apt does not unwrap: both the
>   results pane and the console show that the printed values are
>   Optional("404") and Apartment found: Optional("404"), and in order for
>   404 to appear on console I have to use the ! symbol, which, if I
>   understand correctly, is only needed to manually unwrap regular
>   Optionals.
>
> Why does it happen?

This is just how the console/playground displays the value. In your code example the `apt` is still an `Optional`.

You can check the type at runtime using `dynamicType`, i.e. `println(apt.dynamicType)`

Comment: The second method you wrote is what I normally use for safe unwrapping. My use of the _String!_ type is rather an experiment in order to find out how such an optional would behave inside the statement. Since type inference gives me a _String_ constant as you pointed out, I **had** to explicitly write the type; so it's on purpose. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hmm... Are you saying that despite defining **apt** as an Implicitly Unwrapping Optional it will not unwrap itself and that the first line only appears to unwrap itself because of how the results pane displays code execution?
In that case I still don't understand why the *String!* object inside the function behaves like that while a *String!* object at the top level of the playground file which receives the same return value correctly unwraps itself inside println():
`let str2 :String! = findApt("404");

println(str2)`

Comment: You are not unwrapping the optional if you explicitly use `String!`, the value is still an Optional.

Comment: I Don't agree that the second example is better because the declaration of `findApt` may not be close by. Sure the compiler knows but for a developer it is harder. The second examples is explicit, a developer does not need to find the declaration of `findApt`. I write code to be easy for the next developer to copmplehend (which may be me next year).

Comment: Thanks @aromero; your inputs got me thinking and I discovered that if I define the function as `func findApt(aptNumber :String) -> String!` then **apt** correctly unwraps itself (in fact `println(apt.dynamicType)` which I added to the code inside the if statement now prints out **Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>**), so maybe the Optional return value which I originally wrote for findApt() was ignoring the explicit *String!* type I had written for the definition of **apt**.

Comment: I think the key here is that the construction "if let" is not the same as "let". Note that `let str2 :String! = ...` is an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` as well as if you change the func return type to `String!` as you mentioned in your last comment.